# Cannot GET / Cannot find working directory

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am using Express.js version 4.17.1 to run a server. This is a portion of the server code:

```
// Require dependencies
var path = require('path');
var express = require('express');
var StoreDB = require('../Model/StoreDB');

// Declare application parameters
var PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
var STATIC_ROOT = path.resolve(__dirname, '.../frontend/public');
console.log(__dirname);

// Defining CORS middleware to enable CORS.
// (should really be using "express-cors",
// but this function is provided to show what is really going on when we say "we enable CORS")
function cors(req, res, next){
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS,PUT");
    next();
}

// Declare StoreDB instance
var db = new StoreDB("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017", "cpen400a-bookstore");
console.log(db);

// Instantiate an express.js application
var app = express();

// Configure the app to use a bunch of middlewares
app.use(express.json());                            // handles JSON payload
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended : true }));   // handles URL encoded payload
app.use(cors);                                      // Enable CORS

app.use('/', express.static(STATIC_ROOT));
```

For some reason, when I open up application on the local host, I am presented with the "Cannot GET / " message on my screen. Everything was working before I changed the file structure. The new one is now:

backend/ 
---Server/ 
------index.js 
 
frontend/ 
---public/ 
------index.html

I have tried numerous different methods and it hasn't fixed the issue... Any help would be kind! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please use

```
var STATIC_ROOT = path.resolve(__dirname, '../../frontend/public');
```

**Why:**
from `index.js`, the public directory 's releative path is `../../frontend/public`

Comment: Hey thanks!!! that worked.. :) Do you mind if you could explain to me how that worked? I thought to backspace a folder, you just do one dot, so three dots to get to where I want it to be